# Angular - How to implement a UI interface similar to a tooltip, but that would let me put some controls inside of it and interact with them

Tags: css, angular, sass

I need to create something similar to what is shown in this image:

[image]

I don't think it's a modal. To me it looks more like a tooltip because it is displayed next to the control that is used to open it(calendar icon), but the difference is that I need to place other controls inside that sort of tooltip.

Can you think of any angular component (npm package) similar to what is display in this image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can create like this one using MatDialog. you can use your custom component inside MatDialog also.

```
constructor(
private dialog: MatDialog) {}

showDialog() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YOURCUSTOMCOMPONENT, dialogConfig);
    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
    val => {
          // Read values
    });
}
```

Comment: A matdialog? But how?

Comment: Yeah thanks. But now the problem is the position. I see that I can set the hasBackdrop to false, but is there any way to specify a custom class for the position so that I can place the modal to the right of the button on desktops and to the bottom on mobile devices?

Comment: We can use dialogConfig.position = {
    'top': '0',
    left: '0'
}; for this